# How to record every transaction using Bash

Tags: bash, text-processing

I have a file with debit credit and withdrawal transactions. I need a bash script that records the balance after every transaction. So file is like this:

```
D:11/02/12:1000.50
C:11/03/12:300
W:11/05/12:95.50
D:11/10/12:125
C:11/20/12:265.50
```

where D = debit, C = credit, and W = withdrawal

The output needs to be like this:

```
11/02/12 1000.50
11/03/12 700.50
11/05/12 605.00
```

and so on.  I have done it in `awk` and but cannot figure that out how to write in `bash`.
Any advice or sample would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `bash` doesn't do floating point math. Use `awk`.

Comment: If you already have an `awk` solution, why do you want a Bash solution?

Answer (score 2):

Keep it simple and smart

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
D_amt=0

[[ $# -eq 0 ]] && { echo -e "Usage\n\t $0 input_file"; exit 1; }

while IFS=':' read type Date amt
do
        case $type in
                D)      D_amt=$( echo $amt + $D_amt | bc ) 
                        echo $Date $D_amt && continue ;;

                C|W)    D_amt=$( echo $D_amt - $amt| bc) 
                        echo $Date $D_amt && continue ;;
        esac

done <$1
```

Comment: @l0b0 thanks , I have removed that semicolon

Comment: @user36368 So Please Mark this answer as correct

Answer (score 1):

First the question should be answered whether it makes sense to do that in bash. I really doubt that; the more as there seems to be a working solution. Where is awk unavailable but bash reliably available? Is this homework...?

But on how this can be done: This is not really floating point math but fixed point math with two digits after-point precision. So just shift the numbers by two digits, do the math and shift the result again:

```
shift_100_left () {
  local input output beforep afterp
  input="$1"
  if [ "$input" = "${input//./_}" ]; then
    # no . in it
    output="${input}00"
  else
    beforep="${input%.*}"
    afterp="${input#*.}"
    output="${beforep}${afterp}"
  fi
  output=${output#0}
  output=${output#0}
  echo "$output"
}
shift_100_left 100
shift_100_left 123.75

shift_100_right () {
  local input output beforep afterp length
  input="$1"
  length=${#input}
  if [ 1 -eq "$length" ]; then
    output=0.0${input}
  elif [ 2 -eq "$length" ]; then
    output=0.${input}
  else
    beforep="${input%??}"
    afterp="${input:$((length-2))}"
    output="${beforep}.${afterp}"
  fi
  echo "$output"
}
shift_100_right 1
shift_100_right 12375
```

This asserts that all numbers look like either xxx or yyy.yy but never like e.g. zzz.z.

Comment: seems too complicated !!! :D